# How to rotate head row cell entries of pgfplotstable

Tags: pgfplotstable

How am I able to rotate the first entries of a table with `pgfplotstable`? I have the following table and want to rotate the `descN` labels in the first row.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage[table]{xcolor}
    \usepackage{pgfplotstable}

    \pgfplotstableset{
        every head row/.style={
            before row=\hline,
            after row=\hline\hline
        },
        every last row/.style={
            after row=\hline
        },
        every first column/.style={
            column type/.add={|}{}
        },
        every last column/.style={
            column type=||l|
        },
        color cells/.style={
            col sep=&,
            row sep=\\,
            string type,
            postproc cell content/.code={%
                    \pgfkeysalso{@cell content=\rule{0cm}{2.4ex}%
                    \pgfmathsetmacro\y{max((##1 * 100), 0}%
                    \edef\temp{\noexpand\cellcolor{black!\y}}\temp%
                    \pgfmathtruncatemacro\x\y%
                    \ifnum\x>50 \color{white}\fi%
                    ##1}%
                    },
            columns/x/.style={
                column name={},
                postproc cell content/.code={}
            }
        }
    }

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
    \centering
    \pgfplotstabletypeset[color cells]{
        desc1 & desc2 & desc3 & desc4 & x \\
        0.9 & 0.1 & 0 & 0 & desc1 \\
        0 & 0.8 & 0.1 & 0.1 & desc2 \\
        0 & 0 & 0.95 & 0.05 & desc3 \\
        0 & 0.1 & 0.05 & 0.85 & desc3 \\
    }
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There must be another key to reach this but I can't remember it so I did it a little laborously.

```
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage[table]{xcolor}
    \usepackage{pgfplotstable}

    \pgfplotstableset{
        every head row/.style={
            before row=\hline,
            after row=\hline\hline,
            typeset cell/.code={
            \ifnum\pgfplotstablecol=\pgfplotstablecols
            \pgfkeyssetvalue{/pgfplots/table/@cell content}{\\}%
            \else
            \pgfkeyssetvalue{/pgfplots/table/@cell content}{\rotatebox{90}{##1}&}%
            \fi
            }
        },
        every last row/.style={
            after row=\hline
        },
        every first column/.style={
            column type/.add={|}{}
        },
        every last column/.style={
            column type=||l|
        },
        color cells/.style={
            col sep=&,
            row sep=\\,
            string type,
            postproc cell content/.code={%
                    \pgfkeysalso{@cell content=\rule{0cm}{2.4ex}%
                    \pgfmathsetmacro\y{max((##1 * 100), 0}%
                    \edef\temp{\noexpand\cellcolor{black!\y}}\temp%
                    \pgfmathtruncatemacro\x\y%
                    \ifnum\x>50 \color{white}\fi%
                    ##1}%
                    },
            columns/x/.style={
                column name={},
                postproc cell content/.code={}
            }
        }
    }

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
    \centering
    \pgfplotstabletypeset[color cells]{
        desc1 & desc2 & desc3 & desc4 & x \\
        0.9 & 0.1 & 0 & 0 & desc1 \\
        0 & 0.8 & 0.1 & 0.1 & desc2 \\
        0 & 0 & 0.95 & 0.05 & desc3 \\
        0 & 0.1 & 0.05 & 0.85 & desc3 \\
    }
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Did you remember the key in the mean time? It seems relevant for http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/99121/pgfplotstable-header-in-bold too, where a different but equally kludgy solution was given.

Answer (score 2):

I tried the solution given by @percusse, but it didn't show the desired result, e.g. no rotated header.

It seems that the `typeset cell` key is being ignored by the `every head row` selector - at least with `pgfplotstable` v1.5.1 that I am using.

A slight modification using the [comment](http://sourceforge.net/mailarchive/message.php?msg_id=28632840) on another topic over at sf.net by  Christian Feuersaenger did produce the desired output!

The key change is to apply the `typeset cell` on the whole table and use conditionals to isolate the part of the tabular we want to modify.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\pgfplotstableset{
    %MODIFICATION START
    typeset cell/.append code={%
        \ifnum\pgfplotstablerow<0%head rows are -1
            \ifnum\pgfplotstablecol=\pgfplotstablecols%special treatment for last column
                \pgfkeyssetvalue{/pgfplots/table/@cell content}{\\}%
            \else
                \pgfkeyssetvalue{/pgfplots/table/@cell content}{\rotatebox{90}{#1}&}%
            \fi
        \fi
    },
    every head row/.style={
        before row=\hline,
        after row=\hline\hline,
    },
    %MODIFICATION END
    every last row/.style={
        after row=\hline
    },
    every first column/.style={
        column type/.add={|}{}
    },
    every last column/.style={
        column type=||l|
    },
    color cells/.style={
        col sep=&,
        row sep=\\,
        string type,
        postproc cell content/.code={%
                \pgfkeysalso{@cell content=\rule{0cm}{2.4ex}%
                \pgfmathsetmacro\y{max((##1 * 100), 0}%
                \edef\temp{\noexpand\cellcolor{black!\y}}\temp%
                \pgfmathtruncatemacro\x\y%
                \ifnum\x>50 \color{white}\fi%
                ##1}%
                },
        columns/x/.style={
            column name={},
            postproc cell content/.code={}
        }
    }
}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\centering
\pgfplotstabletypeset[color cells]{
    desc1 & desc2 & desc3 & desc4 & x \\
    0.9 & 0.1 & 0 & 0 & desc1 \\
    0 & 0.8 & 0.1 & 0.1 & desc2 \\
    0 & 0 & 0.95 & 0.05 & desc3 \\
    0 & 0.1 & 0.05 & 0.85 & desc3 \\
}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

In my case I wanted to change the appearance of the head row, so may I suggest modifying the question to a more general form? that way more people with similar problems, like [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/69102/19835) closed question, will be drawn to this discussion.

Thanks again to @percusse and Christian Feuersaenger for pointing me to the right direction. I missed the importance of using `\pgfkeyssetvalue` in the manual `;)`!

Comment: Oh I have version 1.6.1 indeed.

Comment: Nice to see that that's an upcoming feature: I like your solution better!

Comment: By the way, it's now the current version so it's released on CTAN. Hence you might want to update your version. And the question you've linked is closed because there was no MWE or any feedback from the OP.